# Angular Spy on Mock Function called in NgOnInit

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I got a user service that has multiple dependencies. That's why I mocked it to not import those dependencies into the component's test.

### Question:

How do I spy on the call of the mock's function?

### Code:

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {HeaderComponent} from './header.component';
import {HttpClientTestingModule} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../user/user.service';
import {ReplaySubject, Subject} from 'rxjs';
import {User} from '../user/user.interface';

describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

  class MockUserService {
    fakeUser: User = {
      userName: 'Mr. Fake',
      onlineStatus: false
    };
    public userChanged: ReplaySubject<User> = new ReplaySubject<User>();
    constructor() { }
    public getUser(): void {
      this.userChanged.next(this.fakeUser);
    }
  }

  let getUserSpy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HeaderComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [{provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService}],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should query user on load from user service', () => {
    getUserSpy = spyOn<any>(MockUserService, 'getUser');
    expect(getUserSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

I get

```
getUser() method does not exist
```

### Edit Solution

The function must be retrieved with `userService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UserService);` and then spied on before `detectChanges` is called.

```
import {async, ComponentFixture, TestBed} from '@angular/core/testing';

import {HeaderComponent} from './header.component';
import {HttpClientTestingModule} from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA} from '@angular/core';
import {UserService} from '../user/user.service';
import {ReplaySubject} from 'rxjs';
import {User} from '../user/user.interface';

describe('HeaderComponent', () => {
  let component: HeaderComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HeaderComponent>;

  class MockUserService {
    fakeUser: User = {
      userName: 'Mr. Fake',
      onlineStatus: false
    };
    public userChanged: ReplaySubject<User> = new ReplaySubject<User>();
    constructor() { }
    public getUser(): void {
      this.userChanged.next(this.fakeUser);
    }
  }

  let userService: UserService;

  let getUserSpy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [HeaderComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [{provide: UserService, useClass: MockUserService}],
      schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HeaderComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    userService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UserService);
    getUserSpy = spyOn<any>(userService, 'getUser');
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fit('should query user on load from user service', () => {
    expect(getUserSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define marketService variable locally:

```
  it('should query user on load from user service', () => {
    const marketService = TestBed.get(MarketService);
    spyOn<any>(marketService, 'getUser');

    /* call here component method that use marketService.getUser method */
    expect(marketService.getUser).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

or before all tests descriptions:

```
describe('title', () => {
  let marketService: MarketService;


  beforeEach(() => {
    /* others */

    marketService = TestBed.get(MarketService);

    /* others */
  });

  it('expectation', () => {});
});
```

Comment: Thx, `TestBed.get` seems to be deprecated. If I use `.inject`, I can see that it gets called in the logs but the test fails - because of `Expected spy getUser to have been called`.

Comment: yeah, that's right;) in your case you don't call service method:) modified my example

Comment: To add to my sentence before. I think the import would be `userService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(UserService);` But I get the same error. What I'm wondering is that `UserService` is mocked by `UserServiceMock`, so it should get a reference to that, right?

Comment: yes should with DI, the reason that your test failed is you don't call method of component method which contains userService method

Comment: It's in the components ngOnInit. The method gets called for sure I see a log that it was called. I think the problem is rather, that the spy is defined after that. Or that the spy maybe on the wrong thing.

Comment: I got it. See the solution up there. It's an extension to yours. I gave you an upvote.